# Ruby AWS Client Lambda Invocation ReadTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-lambda

My Rails Application Uses AWS SDK v3 to invoke lambda functions as follows

```
        lambda_client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(client_config)
        lambda_return_value = lambda_client.invoke(
        {
            function_name: function_name,
            invocation_type: 'RequestResponse',
            log_type: 'None',
            payload: generated_payload,
        }
```

Most of my lambda functions execute successfully, but the ones that take longer than ~60sec result in the following exception on the ruby side even though the lambda executes completely

```
A Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError occurred in background at 2019-07-11 00:47:18 -0500 :
  Net::ReadTimeout
```

I have gone through the documentation and cannot find a way to set a longer timeout for my lambda invocation. Any ideas how to get ruby to wait for the invocation and not timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Aws::Lambda::Client default timeout is 60 but you can change this while creating new client. Set `:http_read_timeout` in your client_config

```
client_config = {
....
http_read_timeout: 100
}

then create new client

lambda_client = Aws::Lambda::Client.new(client_config)
```

For more reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html

I hope that helpful