# Amazon Lambda re-invoked every minute with multiple request IDs despite having no errors

Tags: python, jenkins, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a Lambda function in Python 3.7 which gets invoked explicitly and synchronously via Boto3. It is configured with a timeout of 5 minutes. While the 1st invocation is in progress for a minute, a second invocation is started with another request ID. Another minute later, the request is again retried, and this time it finished quicky. as it detects the system state has changed. An example sequence of invocations

1. 11:20:29 to 11:21:53 - log stream A - Req. ID: 68cfbd89-9f4c-4e8c-9de0-b9e548983692
2. 11:21:30 to 11:22:56 - log stream B - Req. ID: 1b569ffb-67b8-4e82-8e99-46424f45e2e5
3. 11:22:30 to 11:22:33 - log stream A - Req. ID: d9d60271-4626-43ab-bb3a-f14be057af13

The request ID that's returned from my Lambda call is d9d60271-4626-43ab-bb3a-f14be057af13.

The stack that invokes the Lambda is as follows:

- Jenkins running a Pipeline script.
- The script runs a Makefile which executes 2 sequential tasks.

  - Build a docker container
  - Run a script inside the container.
- The script that runs inside the container is in Python 3.7. It uses Boto3 to call some AWS APIs, then invokes the lambda with `InvocationType="RequestResponse"`.

None of the invocations exits with an unhandled exception or any obvious error. Is Lambda retrying my calls? Could any other element of this stack, notably Jenkins, be "transparently" retrying the task, and if so, how would I establish that?

Comment: To all those who voted to close - as the answer I posted shows, this turned out to be a client-side programming issue. Please withdraw the 'close' votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turned out to arise from Boto3 on the client-side, and not from Lambda! When a lambda returns nothing for more than a minute, Boto3 by default times out. To fix this, I had to override Boto's default config:

```
lambda_config = botocore.config.Config(region_name=region, read_timeout=300)
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda', config=lambda_config)
```

The way I demonstrated this was a client-side problem was by setting the parameter reserved_concurrent_executions to 1, thus preventing concurrent executions of my Lambda, and noting that I get an exception from Boto.

Comment: Incredibly helpful update, and very frustrating how long it took me to find the correct answer for this issue.

Comment: Have seen the same issue when invoked via the CLI. Set --cli-read-timeout = x

Answer (score 6):

This generally occurs due to cli time read out, which returns in multiple invocations of the lambda. Add --cli-read-timeout parameter to 
aws lambda invoke
or if using boto then follow as answered by YitzikC above

For aws cli the command would look like this

`aws lambda invoke --function-name <fn name> --cli-read-timeout 900 --log-type Tail --region <region> /dev/stdout`

Ensure that the cli read timeout is equal to or greater than your lambda fun execution timeout

Answer (score 0):

Lamba function timeout configuration on aws dashboard is time after many retries ( here is 5 minute).
Your request retried after minute, maybe your timeout of lamba client is default about 60 second / request. So if request exceed 60s , lamba will trigger again until reaching 5 minute timeout.
You need increase lamba client timeout.

Check similar issue on Ruby code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56986916/3551956

Comment: indeed, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me. Both function have same VPC setting, without implementing below code, when run child function individually it will successfully executed, but if run from parent function it will give readtimeout error, so added both `connect_timeout` and `read_timeout` value to 900 sec.

```
from botocore import config as botocoreConfig
from boto3 import client as botoClient
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #have added 15 min timeout
    config = botocoreConfig.Config(
       read_timeout=900,
       connect_timeout=900,
       retries={"max_attempts": 0}
   )
   lambdas = botoClient("lambda", config=config)
   payload= {
       "SomePayload": "PayloadValue"
   }


   response = lambdas.invoke(FunctionName="function_to_invoke", 
       InvocationType="RequestResponse", Payload=json.dumps(payload))
```